# How can I post and get a php variable

Tags: php

I used the following php code to get the file extension of an uploaded file:

```
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.
```

But now I want to post this variable to an other php file which saves all the data in a database.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO sounds (id, title, artist, category, subcategory, keywords, upload, format, size, download, rating, ip, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['artist'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['categoryID'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['subcategoryID'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['keywords'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_FILES['upload']['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_FILES['upload']['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_FILES['upload']['size'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['download'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['rating'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ip'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "text"));
```

I know it is probably a stupid question. But how can I post and get this variable?

Comment: Cant you get extension from from this `$_FILES['upload']['name']` ?

Comment: No, this just prints out the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
```

//to insert value into DataBase

```
GetSQLValueString($ext, "text")
```

Comment: I always get the error Column 'format' cannot be null because the variable is not posted from the first php file to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? You don't need to do a POST to save to a database. Just rewrite the other PHP code to be a function and call that function instead.

You should only do a POST if you wish to communicate between two machines (such as between a visitor of your website to your server or your server to another server).

Comment: Sorry, I guess formulated my question quite wrong! I have an upload button which is supposed to post the file extension to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using $_GET ?  It's a lot easier.  Be careful of using $_REQUEST however (I would say it's best practice not to use it).

If you want to POST you could consider using cURL. The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) has plenty of examples so I won't put any extra ones here.

Alternatively it might even be easier to use jQuery to AJAX post.  With just three lines of code you can POST your variables and get a response. Check out the [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/](jQuery manual) which also has examples.  The syntax you would probably use a starting point is:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data) {
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });
```

Personally I would try the AJAX post first...